# Let $f : G \to H$ be a group homomorphism and $a \in G$. Show that if $o(a)$ is finite then $o(a) = q \cdot o(f(a))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $f : G \to H$ be a group homomorphism and $a \in G$. Show that if $o(a)$ is finite then $o(f(a))$ is a divisor of $o(a)$.

Basically I need to show that $o(a) = q \cdot o(f(a))$ for some $q \in \mathbb{N}$. Letting $o(a) = m$ we see that since $f$ is a group homomorphism that

\begin{align*}
o(f(a)) &= \left| \{(f(a))^n \ | \ n \in \mathbb{Z}\}\right|\\
&= \left| \{f(a^n) \ | \ n \in \mathbb{Z}\}\right|
\end{align*}

and since $o(a) = m$ we have that $o(f(a)) = \left| \{f(a^0), \dots, f(a^{m-1})\}\right| \leq m$ (with equality occuring if $f$ is injective)

Now this is the part where I'm stuck at, I'm not sure how to continue from here to show that $o(a) = q \cdot o(f(a))$. I thought that Lagrange's Theorem may be useful here, but I don't see any easy way to make use of it.

How can I prove the above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $G$ be a group. We have that for every $g\in G$ if $g^n = e$ then $o(g) \mid n$ (that is, $n = q\cdot o(g)$ for some $q\in \mathbb{N}$).

Answer (score 2):

Let $n=\operatorname{ord}a$. Then $a^n=e_G$ and therefore $\phi(a)^n=e_H$. But then $\operatorname{ord}\bigl(\phi(a)\bigr)\mid n=\operatorname{ord}a$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the order of $a\in G$ and $m$ the order of $f(a)\in H$. Then $a^n=e_G$ so $e_H=f(e_G)=f(a^n)=f(a)^n$ and thus $m\mid n$. This is because, for any $x\in H$ we have $x^k=e_H$ if and only if $\operatorname{ord}(x)\mid k$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $o(f(a)$ is the quotient $o(a)$ by the cardinal of the kernel of the restriction of $f$ to the subgroup generated by $a$